Estimation of the right metric tensor for a vector-space valued and Normally Distributed random vector
For a fixed value of $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $P^{k}[\mathbb{R}]$ be the real vector space of all real polynomials of degree $< k$. Fix a real closed interval $I = [a, b]$ and $k$ distinct values $a = x_1 < \ldots < x_k = b$.
I have a dataset of $n$ observations, the $i$-th observation is a sampling $(x_1, y_{i1}), ..., (x_k, y_{ik})$ of an unknown differentiable function $f_i: I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_i(x_j) =  y_{ij}$.
Let $\mathbf{e}_j$ be the Lagrange polynomial interpolating the points $((x_1, 0), ..., (x_j, 1), ..., (x_k, 0))$.
Then $\mathbf{e}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{e}_k$ is a basis of $P^{k}[\mathbb{R}]$.
I identify a vector $\mathbf{y}_i = (y_{i1}, ...., y_{ik}) \in \mathbb{R}^k$ with the Lagrange interpolating polynomial $p \in P^{k}[\mathbb{R}]$ through the points $(x_1, y_{i1}), ..., (x_k, y_{ik})$.
This way I see $\mathbf{y}_i = (y_{i1}, ...., y_{ik})$ as one outcome of a random vector $Y$ taking values in a vector space $V$ isomorphic to $P^{k}[\mathbb{R}]$, via the isomorphism that associates
the canonical basis vector $(0, ..., 1, ..., 0) \in \mathbb{R}^k$ (1 in $j$-th position) with $\mathbf{e}_j$.
The inner product that I consider on $V$ is induced by
$$\langle f, g\rangle = \int_I f(\alpha)g(\alpha) d\alpha$$
through the correspondence between the $k$-tuple of points $((x_1, y_{i1}), ..., (x_k, y_{ik}))$ and its Lagrange interpolating polynomial.
Let $\boldsymbol{\mu} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{y}_i$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbf{y}_i-\boldsymbol{\mu})(\mathbf{y}_i-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T$ (outer product in $\mathbb{R}^k$).
I want to find the components of the metric tensor $M$ of $V$.
If $M$ is the $k \times k$ real symmetric matrix representing the inner product on $V$ w.r.t. the canonical basis (which is not orthonormal in this case), then the covariance matrix of the data is $M \boldsymbol{\Sigma} M^T$. Of course,
$$(M)_{ij} = \langle \mathbf{e}_i, \mathbf{e}_j\rangle$$
but due to numerical approximation errors, I could not compute these numbers directly (in my case $k = 224$).
So another approach to estimate the metric tensor could be to find one symmetric and positive semi-definite matrix $M$ for which the distribution
$$f_{Y}(\mathbf{y})=((2 \pi)^{k}|M \boldsymbol{\Sigma} M^T|)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{y}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^{\top} (M \boldsymbol{\Sigma} M^T)^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\right)$$
fits best the frequencies observed in the dataset. Any suggestion is welcome, either by analytical means or with use of neural networks.
